# Paperclip preview files before downloading, also generate share link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am starting up with rails and was going thru the [sharebox-tutorial](http://codyaray.com/downloads/2012/03/How-to-Build-a-Dropbox-like-Sharing-App-using-Ruby-on-Rails.html).
Now is it possible with paperclip to first preview the uploaded files and then choose the download link, rather than the file directly being downloaded when link is clicked, as in the tutorial and elsewhere in the internet.

Also, what will be the method to generate a share link unique to every friend email.

While researching, i also found out that files should be uploaded in some other folder but public.
how is it different from storing the files in public folder with the url hashed. the hash url is still accessible when user is logged out.

UPDATE
the preview i am referring to should be after uploading.

Comment: Are you talking about previewing the image before it's saved to the DropBox? Or preview the image before it's downloaded by another user?

Comment: If you have already uploaded the file, it will be a relatively simple process. However, if you are talking about previewing a to-be-uploaded file, this will require more code. It would help if you were clearer

Comment: preview after it is uploaded. that is, when user wishes to just view the file uploaded, later some time.